# React Konva share ref between sibling components throws error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, konvajs, react-ref, react-konva

I have `App.tsx` which contains 2 sibling components:

- `Konva.tsx`: It has the Canvas
- `Options.tsx`: It has a *Download Canvas* button

So I created a `ref` named `stageRef` in `App.tsx` to pass it to `Konva.tsx` & `Options.tsx`. I use `React.forwardRef` to forward refs to child components.

## App.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
import type { Stage as StageType } from 'konva/types/Stage'

import { Konva, Options } from '@/components/index'
import { FrameItProvider } from '@/store/index'

const App = () => {
  const stageRef = React.createRef<StageType>()

  return (
    <>
      <Konva ref={stageRef} />
      <Options ref={stageRef} />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

In `Konva.tsx`, the `ref` points to the Canvas so it can access the element in the DOM.

## Konva.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'

import { useFrameItStore } from '@/store/index'
import { BrowserWindow } from '@/components/index'

import type { Window } from '@/types/index'
import type { Stage as StageType } from 'konva/types/Stage'

interface IProps {
  className?: string
}

export const Konva = observer(
  React.forwardRef<StageType, IProps>(({ className }: IProps, forwardedRef) => {
    const frameItStore = useFrameItStore()
    const browser: Window = frameItStore.browser

    return (
      <>
        <Stage
          width={browser.width}
          height={browser.height}
          ref={forwardedRef}
          className={className}
        >
          <Layer>
            <BrowserWindow />
          </Layer>
        </Stage>
      </>
    )
  })
)
```

In `Options.tsx`, I trigger the download call using `downloadImage` with the `forwardedRef`.

## Options.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'
import type { Stage as StageType } from 'konva/types/Stage'

import { useFrameItStore } from '@/store/index'
import type { TrafficSignalStyle } from '@/types/index'

interface IProps {
  className?: string
}

export const Options = observer(
  React.forwardRef<StageType, IProps>((props: IProps, forwardedRef) => {
    const frameItStore = useFrameItStore()

    const downloadImage: (stageRef: React.ForwardedRef<StageType>) => void =
      frameItStore.downloadImage

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => downloadImage(forwardedRef)}>
          Download Canvas
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  })
)
```

I'm using MobX to manage my store. However, the `forwardRef` causes problem.

## store/index.ts

```
import type { Stage as StageType } from 'konva/types/Stage'

import type { IFrameItStore } from '@/types/index'

export class FrameItStore implements IFrameItStore {
  downloadImage(stageRef: React.ForwardedRef<StageType>) {
    console.log(stageRef)
    stageRef
      .current!.getStage()
      .toDataURL({ mimeType: 'image/jpeg', quality: 1 })
  }
}
```

## types/index.ts

```
export interface IFrameItStore {
    downloadImage(stageRef: React.ForwardedRef<StageType>): void
}
```

I get 2 TypeScript errors in `store/index.ts`:

> TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

on `stageRef` when I try to access `stageRef.current` and

> ```
>   TS2339: Property 'current' does not exist on type '((instance: Stage | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<Stage | null>'.
> ```

Property 'current' does not exist on type '(instance: Stage | null) => void'.

on `current`

I tried not using `ForwardedRef` but it gave error that the types do not match so I have to use `ForwardedRef` but I'm not sure how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a `ref` in `App.tsx` & then passed it to `Konva.tsx`. I catched the ref using `React.forwardRef` function.

Then I used the lesser known `useImperativeHandle` hook in `Konva.tsx` to access the function `downloadImage` in `App.tsx` & then pass the function `downloadImage` directly to `Options.tsx`.

I didn't keep anything in MobX store. Just kept it locally in `Konva` component where its easily accessible. The old rule is that if it isn't going to be used in any other component, then it should be kept as close to the component as possible.

## App.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'

import { Konva, Options } from '@/components/index'

const App = () => {
  const stageRef = React.useRef<{ downloadImage: Function }>(null)

  return (
    <>
      <Konva ref={stageRef} />
      <Options downloadImage={() => stageRef?.current?.downloadImage()} />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

## Konva.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'

import { useFrameItStore } from '@/store/index'
import { BrowserWindow } from '@/components/index'

import type { Window } from '@/types/index'
import type { Stage as StageType } from 'konva/types/Stage'

interface IProps {
  className?: string
}

interface ForwardedRef {
  downloadImage: Function
}

export const Konva = observer(
  React.forwardRef<ForwardedRef, IProps>(
    ({ className }: IProps, forwardedRef) => {
      const frameItStore = useFrameItStore()
      const browser: Window = frameItStore.browser

      const stageRef = React.useRef<StageType>(null)

      React.useImperativeHandle(
        forwardedRef,
        () => ({
          downloadImage: () =>
            stageRef.current
              ?.getStage()
              .toDataURL({ mimeType: 'image/jpeg', quality: 1 }),
        }),
        []
      )

      return (
        <Stage
          width={browser.width}
          height={browser.height}
          ref={stageRef}
          className={className}
        >
          <Layer>
            <BrowserWindow />
          </Layer>
        </Stage>
      )
    }
  )
)
```

## Options.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'

interface IProps {
  className?: string
  downloadImage: Function
}

export const Options = observer((props: IProps) => {
  const { downloadImage } = props

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => console.log(downloadImage())}>
        Download Image
      </button>
    </div>
  )
})
```

Here's a complete working demo on CodeSandBox → https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-share-refs-between-siblings-dsd97?file=/src/App.tsx